# Grails - Maven Error installing Spring Security Plugin 3.0.4 on IntellJ Idea

Tags: java, maven, grails, intellij-idea, grails-plugin

I have a problem installing Spring Security Core 3.0.4 plugin into my Grails 3.1.5 project. Here what I am using:

Grails: 3.1.5

IntellJ Idea: Ultimate 2016.1.1

Maven: 3.0.5

In `build.gradle`, I have:

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    ...
}
...
dependencies {
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.4"
    ...
}
```

When I do "Tools" > "Grails" > "Synchronize Grails settings", I get this error:

```
Configuring > 1/1 projects| Error Error initializing classpath: Could not find spring-security-core.zip (org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.0.4).
Searched in the following locations:
https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/3.0.4/spring-security-core-3.0.4.zip (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
```

So, for some reason, it is looking for a `.zip` file. However, looking at the directory https://repo.grails.org/grails/core/org/grails/plugins/spring-security-core/3.0.4/ there is no `.zip` file in there. Any clue on how to resolve this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try new version Spring Security eg:

```
compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.9.RELEASE'
```

Comment: I pointed at the local repository and made it a priority over remote repository which solved it among other things such as cleaning up some plugins that are not compatible with spring security 3 such as twitter plugin (as of the time of writing)